# Remote connection to MySQL (110 error)

Tags: mysql

I have db conifg on server

```
$db['app']['hostname'] = 'db.host.com';
$db['app']['username'] = 'User';
$db['app']['password'] = 'Password';
$db['app']['database'] = 'DB1';
```

I need to import database from local machine to remote sql.
So, as you can see, db is on db.host.com

source code is on host.com

So I can try something like this:

```
mysql -h db.host.com -u User -p DB1 < /var/www/html/myapp/db/dbdump.sql
```

And i got this:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db.host.com' (110)
```

I did this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

and in iptables - L I have

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp   dpt:mysql

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

But I have still same error and can not import db.

Comment: Does the machine's MySQL server listen for connection from outside?

Comment: @mrsolupo Can you share your solution?